# Django+heroku shows time of response which grows linnearly against volume of data - what to do?

Tags: django, performance, heroku, time, response

[image: Green bar means 4+ secomds before data transfer (blue bar)][image: Records in table and time of response]

What should I change to make the time shorter?
[image]

I experimented with numer of records in output table. I pass the number as parameter. Time of processing on server is the same. But time of pause before data transfer is growing fast